# Is it normal or acceptable Spanish to drop "estar" from phrases with "donde"?

Tags: traducción

I'm reading a book where this keeps occurring. Would it sound normal if I said this?

> "Regresó donde ellos."

and

> "Tengo que ir donde Martha."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, Spanish is very diverse, and geography plays a big part in how the language is used. In the cases that you mentioned, it sounds like the Spaniard accent. However in Latin America people would look at you funny for a heartbeat.

It is not wrong in itself because it still has a subject, an action and a 'predicado'

Comment: I can confirm that, I'm from Spain and the sentences sound perfectly normal to me.

Comment: Actually the having a subject predicate etc isn't what's going on. It's that donde is normally a relative adverb, but in this case, it's actually a preposition. With people, it generally means their house

Comment: Sorry to disagree with Arturo. I'm from Colombia and those sentences sound perfect to me. Some people around here would use 'adonde' instead of 'donde' but nobody would look at you funny around here. It would be good if Arturo can tell us where he is from (no info on his profile)

Comment: I'm from Mexico, and it sounded funny, but I've heard other people from Spain say it before so it is not too rare

Comment: Although in Mexico it is rarely used that way, it is far from funny or weird. Anyone would understand the meaning. When chatting in an informal setting, someone may suggest you to use another preposition like "con" or "adonde" (as DGaleano states.) In writing form, however, using "donde" or "adonde" is correct (and even preferable due to the fact that "con" means "with".)